# Dojo 1.7 Build: Out of Memory Errors

Tags: java, javascript, ant, build, dojo

After upgrading to Dojo 1.7.3, our ant build that was working flawlessly for years on previous versions of Dojo is now completely non-operational due to out of memory errors:

```
[java] starting writing resources...
[java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.getArgsArray(Interpreter.java:4623)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3335)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2484)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(NativeArray.java:1565)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(NativeArray.java:313)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3335)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2484)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c62(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c69(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c40(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c42(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Unknown Source)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3335)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2484)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
[java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
[java] js: exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I have extensively documented our troubles [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Build-fail-in-1-7-upgrade-td3986632.html).

In particular, where I note:

> If I run my build straight from the CL as a Java command, with the '
>   --optimize shrinksafe" switch, it fails, but without it succeeds.  (running it with internStrings alone seems to cause other errors).
>
> Not sure what to make of this, since I believe that oprtimize defaults
>   to shrinksafe, but I have determined the following:
>
> WORKS:
>
> c:\temp\dojo-release-1.7.3rc1-src\util\buildscripts>java -Xms256m
>   -Xmx256m  -cp ../shrinksafe/js.jar;../closureCompiler/compiler.jar;../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar
>   org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  ../../dojo/dojo.js
>   baseUrl=../../dojo load=build -p
>   C:\company\builds\head\build\generated\general\comComplete.profile.js
>   --action release --releaseDir C:\company\builds\head\build\generated\general\htdocs\company\javascript\1420
>
> BROKEN (out of memory errors):
>
> c:\temp\dojo-release-1.7.3rc1-src\util\buildscripts>java -Xms256m
>   -Xmx256m  -cp ../shrinksafe/js.jar;../closureCompiler/compiler.jar;../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar
>   org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  ../../dojo/dojo.js
>   baseUrl=../../dojo load=build -p
>   C:\company\builds\head\build\generated\general\comComplete.profile.js
>   --action release --releaseDir C:\company\builds\head\build\generated\general\htdocs\company\javascript\1420
>   --optimize shrinksafe --internStrings true
>
> Unfortunately, the following ant script target continues to fail with
>   memory errors:
>
> BuildNum: ${buildNum}
>
> ```
>   <path id="js.path">             <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
>   </path>
>
>   <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="js.path.unix" refid="js.path"
> ```
>
> />        js.path.unix: ${js.path.unix}
>
> ```
>   <!-- clean unpack and output dirs -->       <delete
> ```
>
> dir="${outputDir}/htdocs/company/javascript/src/" />
>
> ```
>   <copy file="${externalDir}/dojo/companyComplete.profile.js"
> ```
>
> tofile="${outputDir}/companyComplete.profile.js" filtering="yes"
>   overwrite="yes">
>
> ```
>   <java fork="true"
>       dir="${outputDir}/htdocs/company/javascript/src/util/buildscripts"
>       classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main"
> ```
>
> failonerror="true">                                 
>                 
>                 
>                 
>                                                                                                       -->
>             --> -->          -->

---

**Update 1**

I've also tried it with:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xms5120m"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx5120m"/>
```

And also using the `maxmemory` setting on the ant java task itself.

Comment: I take it that just increasing the available memory is not an option? 256m seems pretty small for a build. Does it succeed with 1g?

Comment: I've tried it with up to 5 gigs of heap space.  No love.  (Thanks for taking a look)

Comment: From http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/how-to-resolve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-in-jboss/ maybe try to just disable that error? I'm guessing it won't help but it's worth a try. Add this flag to disable that particular exception -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Comment: @jjathman In that case I get `js: exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the problem, the releaseDir switch value had both windows and unix file separators in it.  That used to work fine in Dojo < 1.6 and typically Java has no problem with it.  For some reason, the Dojo 1.7 build system hits memory problems in that case.

The releaseDir, after resolving the ant tokens from the question, had a mix of both unix and windows file separators:

```
<arg value="releaseDir=${output.dir}/path/foo/bar" /> 
-> Became -> 
releaseDir=blah\blah\blah/path/foo/bar
```

And that was enough to cause the build to lock up at 'writing resources' and then crash with 'out of heap space'.  (This is something Java normally handles without issue).

The fix was simple enough:

```
<path id="dojo.output.tmp">
    <pathelement location=" ${output.dir}/path/foo/bar "/>
</path>

<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="dojo.output.dir" refid="dojo.output.tmp" />
...
<arg value="releaseDir=${dojo.output.dir}" />
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue without ant, just trying to use Windows to do the build with a batch file under 1.8.2. There seems to be a problem if you don't use Unix style "/" when defining releaseDir. If you use Windows style "\" you get the memory errors at writeResources as described.